# Regarding julia plots and plotly backend

Tags: julia, plotly, plots.jl

I recently changed from julia 0.6.4 to 1.1.1

I have an issue with the julia plots package plotly() backend which was very nice in the 0.6.4 version as i could manipulate some aspects of the plot "live" (zoom, saving,..)

I am ploting two same sized vectors.

In summary, just changed the kernel from 0.6.4 to 1.1.1

The error displayed is this one:

only png or svg allowed. got: :html

I would preferably not change my backend as this one was very confortable.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: There are some issues with `Plotly` and `PlotlyJS` at the moment. You can work around [the issue](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyJS.jl/issues/278) for `PlotlyJS` by downgrading `WebIO` to `0.7.0` with `] add WebIO@0.7.0`. You may want to pin the package at this version. The issue with `Plotly` does not go away even after downgrading `WebIO` but you can use `PlotlyJS` backend.

Comment: I get "Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package WebIO [0f1e0344]:" and a list of possible versions I can try (which don't work either..) Do you recommend any other backend for interactive use?
Nothing super powerful, just want to make zoom in the plots without changing code, saving without altering the code..... Tools that I had on 0.6.4 with plotly() backend

Comment: I do not know what kind of plots do you need but maybe try [`VegaLite.jl`](https://github.com/fredo-dedup/VegaLite.jl/). You may add pan & zoom by adding `selection={
                  grid={
                      type="interval", bind="scales"}}` to `@vlplot` macro call as a parameter.